# Performance for Avg & Max in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, average

I want to decrease the query execution time for the following query.
This query is taking around 1 min 20 secs for about 2k records.

Numbers of records in table: 1348474

Number of records processed through where query: 25000

Number of records returned: 2152

```
SELECT Col1, Col2,
ISNULL(AVG(Col3),0) AS AvgCol,
ISNULL(MAX(Col3),0) AS MaxCol,
COUNT(*) AS Col5
FROM TableName WITH(NOLOCK)
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
ORDER BY Col1, MaxCol DESC
```

I tried removing the AVG & MAX columns and it lowered to 1 sec.
Is there any optimized solution for the same?
I have no other indexing other than Primary key.

**Update**

Indexes added:
nonclustered located on PRIMARY - Col1

nonclustered located on PRIMARY - Col2

clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY - Id

======

Thanks in advance..Happy coding !!!

Comment: Does your comparison query have an `ORDER BY`?  How many rows are produced by the query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, order by is there. 2k records are produced

Comment: If you really want performance help then you need to provide some details. A fake query against a non-existent table is pretty much asking for people to guess. Provide the table definition including indexes in addition to approximate row count. And keep in mind that NOLOCK is NOT a magic go fast button. It has some very serious ramifications. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for the link, but the real table won't make any difference with my concern towards the MAX and AVG functions. updating the question with number of records processed and indexing added

Comment: The row counts are good but the important part "Provide the table definition including indexes" is still missing. And yes the NOLOCK will have an impact even on aggregates. But maybe in this case it is ok to not be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2,
       COALESCE(AVG(Col3), 0) AS AvgCol,
       COALESCE(MAX(Col3), 0) AS MaxCol,
       COUNT(*) AS Col5
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
ORDER BY Col1, MaxCol DESC;
```

I would start with an index on `(Col1, Col2, Col3)`.

I'm not sure if this will help.  It is possible that the issue is the time for ordering the results.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but this has decreased the performance more. I think COALESCE is taking more time than ISNULL. Also would like to inform that ORDER BY is not creating any difference. Also added indexing, reduced around 10 secs

Comment: @DeepShah . . . You have not added the index recommended in this answer.